# ColdFusion Query Loop Next Value

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

Hello I have query array with values

- cat_1 abc
- cat_1 bbb
- cat_1 ccc
- cat_2 abc
- cat_2 ooo
- cat_3 ppo

now I have to display this array in the following manner

cat_1

- abc
- bbb
- ccc

cat_2

- abc
- ooo

cat_3

- ppo

I have using a table with associations to get join data from categories and item tables but when I output it to my view. I am not sure how to get the next value of the row in the query loop.

```
<cfloop query="checklist">
#checklist.categoriesname# #checklist.name#
</cfloop>
```

Above is my current loop, I want to get the categoriesname once and if is the same as last not output it.

Comment: (Edit) Have you looked at using a grouped cfoutput instead of a cfloop? ie `<cfoutput query="..." group="...">`. It does exactly what you need. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170553/getting-all-sub-records-in-a-one-to-many-relationship/5170598#5170598).  However, to answer the question asked, you can access any query row using array notation, ie   `queryName.columnName[RowNumber]`. Though in this case a grouped output is simpler.

Comment: thank you it helped. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2359-coldfusion-10---using-the-group-attribute-with-cfloop-to-group-query-rows.htm this link is also useful

Comment: sorry I accidently flag your comments, dunno how to undo

Comment: Heh, no worries. Not sure you can undo a "flag".  If not, a moderator will probably read the comments and realize it was done accidentally and dismiss it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot cfloop had a group attribute now too. I was going to vote to close as a duplicate, but you should post the cfloop tip as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested above, code resolve the issue for me.

```
<cfloop query="checklist" group="categoriesname">
#checklist.categoriesname#
<cfloop>
#checklist.name#
</cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Within <cfloop> #checklist.categoriesname# and #checklist.name# need a <cfoutput> tag, to actually display the values.

Comment: One important note for those unfamiliar with [the "group" feature](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfloop%3A+looping+over+a+query), in order for it to work properly, the underlying query results *must* be sorted by the grouped column. From the docs, the group feature: *"...Eliminates adjacent duplicate rows when data is sorted. Use if you retrieved a recordset ordered on one or more query columns. For example, if a recordset is ordered on "Customer_ID", you can group the output on "Customer_ID.".*